# How can I catch an insert on a table statement in plsql , calculate a unique value based on input column names and column values

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have to capture an insert statement's column names and column values , based on these 2 inputs I need to calculate a unique column value(sub-partition) and assign it to this insert so that the insert goes into a particular sub-partition of this table.

Comment: Why do you have to calculate the sub partition key programmatically? Couldn't you subpartition by a virtual column?

Comment: @WilliamRobertson.. I can't use a virtual column

Comment: You can try using a Trigger on an event of BEFORE INSERT, you can use this mykong example : https://mkyong.com/oracle/oracle-plsql-before-insert-trigger-example/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "capturing" the `INSERT` statement.

From my point of view, you should **compose** it (the `INSERT`) yourself, using **dynamic SQL**.

My database is XE and it doesn't support partitioning, so I'd rather not *guess* it and not being able to *test* it; you'd, of course, use your own syntax. I'm using CASE to decide whether someone's `COMM` columns should get a value or not; you'd do  it similarly.

Procedure:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test
  2    (p_empno  in varchar2,
  3     p_ename  in varchar2,
  4     p_sal    in number)
  5  is
  6    l_str varchar2(200);
  7  begin
  8    l_str := 'insert into test (empno, ename, sal, comm) ' ||
  9             'values (' ||
 10              p_empno ||', '||
 11              chr(39) || p_ename || chr(39) || ', ' ||
 12              p_sal ||', '||
 13              case when p_sal < 1000 then 100 else 0 end ||')';
 14    dbms_output.put_line(l_str);
 15    execute immediate l_str;
 16  end;
 17  /

Procedure created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on;
SQL> exec p_test(1, 'Little', 750);
insert into test (empno, ename, sal, comm) values (1, 'Little', 750, 100)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> exec p_test(1, 'Foot', 2000);
insert into test (empno, ename, sal, comm) values (1, 'Foot', 2000, 0)

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> select * From test;

     EMPNO ENAME             SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1 Little            750        100
         1 Foot             2000          0

SQL>
```

Comment: Your point about composing the insert correctly in the first place is spot on IMHO, using `CASE`, etc. In your _specific_ example though, why use dynamic sql at all and not bind variables? I wouldn't use dynamic sql unless the actual table or column _name_ was an unknown...

Comment: Because, @pmdba, they said "... based on input **column names** and column values".

Comment: I understand; that just isn't what you put in your example. Thus my confusion...

Answer (score 0):

@Littlefoot , Thanks as in insert into abc ('name','empid','partition_id') values ('nparab',2000,10); The value of partition_id=10 is not known it will be calculated based on name and empid combination...I even dont knw the incoming insert statement , can i use trigger to catch the incoming insert then I can pass the column name and column value to let say a function and that function based on input combination of column name and column value calculates the partition_id and the function returns partition_id which is picked by the incoming insert so that insert statement goes in respective subpartition based on the partition_id